# the_field - ACF not working in 'while' loop

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

Main string of code (that doesn't work):
`<span class="price-in-kune"><?php the_field('tariff_price_kn') ?> kn</span>`

```
 <?php 

 $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'tariffs',
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'type_of_site' => 'landing_page_type',

 );

 $webTariffs = new WP_Query($args);

 while ($webTariffs->have_posts()) {
  $webTariffs->the_post();?>

  <div class="pricing-item">
    <div class="pricing-item-header">

      <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
      <span class="price-in-kune"><?php the_field('tariff_price_kn') ?> kn</span>

    </div>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

[image]

The ways i tried to solve this problem:

1. put insted of `the_field('tariff_price_kn')` - `echo('hi')` - the code worked
2. add `$post_id -> the_field('tariff_price_kn', $post_id)`
3. `$currencyKune = get_field('tariff_price_kn');` And then `echo $currencyKune`

P.S 3) i don't know exactly where should i put `$currencyKune = get_field('tariff_price_kn')`, so i put it before while at first time - doesn't work and at the second time i put it after `$webTariffs->the_post();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
            <?php 
            $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'tariffs',
            'posts_per_page' => 3
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            ?>
            <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-sm-6">

            <h2 class="the-title"><?php the_field('tariff_price_kn', $post->ID); ?> +  <?php the_title() ;?> </h2>


            </div>

            <?php endwhile; else: ?> Nothing here <?php endif; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: i need also to display only landing_page_type of type_of_sites

Comment: but also even like this gives 0 results. Maybe it's problem not with the code? The title displays, but any fields - not

Comment: I've just tried using thinker's solution in my own website (but replacing the post_type & ACF field) and it worked exactly as required. I'd suggest taking a look at your ACF structure setup. Perhaps there's something not set correctly there.

Beyond that, it would be a good idea to try run the following code as a way to confirm that your ACF values are being saved correctly to the posts. Change out #POSTID# with a post in the tariffs post type that definitely has a tariff_price_kn value set.

`var_dump(get_field('tariff_price_kn', #POSTID#));exit;`